# How can I set the root view controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

How can I set the root view controller programmatically based on some condition? For example, if a user has logged in, he/she will see an "content" view controller when he/she opens the app; if a user has not logged in, he/she will see an "register/login" view controller when he/she opens the app. So, can someone give me some pointers and guides. Thanks.

Comment: What is your setup: are you using a storyboard, NIBs, or all programatic views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you can keep the flag in NSUserdefault about previous login and token if you have .

so when the app did launch  method check if flag is set for login , if yes then make the content controller as root controller , else make login controller as root controller

Answer (score 0):

Keep the flags in Either NSUserDefaults or NSNotificationCenter for previous Login.